# How do you force an embedded audio file to autostart on an Android Tablet?

Tags: android, html, audio, html5-audio

I have a Nabi (Android Tablet), and I am designing a website and I have an audio file that I want to play when the audio file is on the page.

On the Nabi, it shows up, but I have to press play. It doesn't just start. Here's the code:

```
<embed src="windchimes.mp3" height="100px" width="100px" autostart="true">
```

or

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"><source src="windchimes.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

Does anybody know how to make it so that I don't have to push play on the tablet?

Comment: Have you checked taking this functionality out of HTML5 and using JS? Normally you have more freedom... Perhaps howler.js?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this rapresented an easy solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011906/4622767
Copy & paste this in your chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback
```

My web app has many page reload so I can't force the user to press a button every time; but it is for internal usage, so I can force the users to use chrome and configure that option.